# How to pass a model instance to all controllers and views based on a route parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am working on a Laravel control panel project where we should be able to toggle from one site to another and get the detail of the site based on the ID passed in the route.

In itself this is quiet easy to do but as I will have several controllers using this technique it means for each controller and each controller instance I will have collect the site instance and it does not look very user friendly due to the many repetitions.

Here is what I have:
Route:

```php
Route::get(
    'cp/site/{website}/modules/feeds',
    'App\Http\Controllers\Modules_sites\Feeds\FeedController@index'
)->name('module_site.feeds.index');
```

Model:

```php
class Website extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primaryKey ='site_id';
}
```

The database is simple with an id (site_id) and name

Controller:

```php
public function index(Website $website)
{
    dd($website -> name);  
}
```

The above is working fine but I am going to end with dozens of methods across multiple controllers doing the same thing, and what if changes are required.

I have looked at the ID of using the `AppServiceProvider` to create the `Website` instance and then pass it to the controllers and views but I can't do this as the route is not defined at this stage and I only seem to be able to pass this to the view.

Essentially, I am looking to create something similar to the `auth()->user()` method that is available from controllers and routes without the needs to pass it to each controller.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use middleware to set this value? Something like this to put it in the session globally:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CheckWebsite
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): mixed
    {
        $request->session()->put("website", $request->route("website"));
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Or this on a per-controller basis:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Modules_sites\Feeds;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FeedController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function (Request $request, Closure $next) {
            $this->website = $request->route("website");
            return $next($request);
        });
    }

    public function index()
    {
        dd($this->website->name);
    }
}
```

Also worth mentioning that routes are not defined like that in Laravel 8 any longer. It should look like this:

```php
Route::get(
    'cp/site/{website}/modules/feeds',
    [FeedController::class, 'index']
)->name('module_site.feeds.index');
```

With an appropriate import for the controller class.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great using the middleware solution meaning I can access the website info from the controllers or views using the session.
Just a note for others to say that $request->session ->put gives an error and works with $request->session()->put instead

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer to fix the typo.

Answer (score 0):

as you primary key is not `id` so it will not work automatically you need to tell laravel to search by column name

code will be

```php
Route::get('cp/site/{website:site_id}/modules/feeds', 'App\Http\Controllers\Modules_sites\Feeds\FeedController@index')->name('module_site.feeds.index');
```

you need to use `{website:site_id}`
ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name